# Introductory math Olympiad question

Tags: proof-writing, contest-math

This is a question from the book " A First Step to Mathematical Olympiad Problems" by Derek Holton.

> This is the question and the other things that lead to the the problem, directly from the
> [image]

Now the Thing that I am having trouble with is explaining how the numbers that are less than $ c $
i.e. $(r-1)(s-1)$ for $HCF(r,s)=1$ but are not purely multiples of only $r$ or $s$ ,

$e.g.$ if $r=3$ , $s=11$ , we can form $ 17= 3\times2 +11\times1$

and we can find many more examples like these for other values of $r$ and $s$
,but I could not figure out a general form for these, without using some extra functions, which led to the proof getting a bit difficult to make.

The hints section mentions the ticks and crosses ,and grouping them together in some way, but I seem to have no  clue how to do it in a way that would lead to the solution

Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Look for a symmetry in the numbers that can and can't be represented.

Comment: Try listing out more tables and finding a pattern. This is the chicken mcnugget theorem/frobenius coin problem.